# Как сделать проксирование картинок на другой домен в nginx?

Tags: nginx, http, https

1. Есть например домен с картинками - **img.site.com**.
   Как сделать так чтобы при запросе **mysite.com/img/logo.png** вместо **mysite.com** незаметно ( нужно чтобы никто не знал откуда я беру картинки ) подставился **img.site.com**?
2. Как в nginix поставить программною логику: **img.site.com** нету картинки (404) то использовать **img2.site.com** ?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Можно, например, проксировать запросы

```
server {
  # default settings for mysite.com

  server_name mysite.com;

  # Если нужны только картинки
  location /img/ {
   proxy_pass http://img.site.com;
   proxy_redirect     off;
   proxy_set_header   Host  "img.site.com";
   proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

  # Здесь остальная конфигурация для mysite.com
}
```

В этом случае, все запросы на mysite.com вида http://mysite.com/img/logo.png будут отправляться на http://img.site.com/img/logo.png

При этом следует понимать, что до отправки картинки клиенту будет сделан подзапрос на img.site.com, на который так же расходуется время.

Для сокращения времени ответа можно настроить кэширование, чтобы не отправлять подзапросы каждый раз при запросе одной и той же картинки.